# How to fire an event when dropdown inside Repeater changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I want to do some actions in my database when user change dropdown's selectedIndex.Now I have the following.

```
<td class="shop-item-qty">
<asp:DropDownList ID="qtyDropDownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="changeCount" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="ItemId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("GiftVoucher.ID") %>'/>
</td>
```

All I want is to get my hidden fields value in `changeCount` method. The problem is that I can't directly get hidden fields value, because this code is in `Repeater` element. How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: Chuck Norris can directly get hidden field values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected void qtyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      DropDownList control = (DropDownList)sender;

      RepeaterItem rpItem = control.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
      if (rpItem != null)
      {
         HiddenField hiddenField = ((HiddenField)rpItem.FindControl("ItemId"));    
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `GiftVoucher.ID` value to DropDown's custom attribute and skip HiddenField:

`<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="qtyDropDownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="changeCount" AutoPostBack="true" data-itemId='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />`

```
protected void changeCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = ((DropDownList)sender).Attributes["data-itemId"];
}
```

Comment: I guess Eval will not work in my case, because I've binded my dropdown to another datasource. Thanks for your answer.